# Operator overloading / support discriminated unions in F#

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, overloading, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union (tagged value) which is supposed to represent the degree of a polynomial

```
type Degree =
    |MinusInf
    |Fin of int
```

So I have a function which gives me the degree of a polynomial

```
>deg [1;2;3;4];;
val it : Degree = Fin 3
```

Now, my question is, how can I make a function which allows me to add degrees so that:

```
 Fin 2 + Fin 3 = Fin 5
```

All best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly detailed article on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading). In short, you want to define a function like this on your `Degree` type:

```
type Degree =
    |MinusInf
    |Fin of int
    static member (+) (a: Degree, b: Degree) : Degree =
        match a, b with
        | Fin x, Fin y -> Fin (x+y)
        | _, _ -> MinusInf

let x = Fin 2 + Fin 3
```

Comment: Thank you, scrwtp!
I'm glad you included the link for MSDN. It is much more difficult to find information about F# than languages such as Java or Python :)